# Concerning the Gilbert Strang's book about algebra and the special solution of the nullspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*Unfortunately I don't have yet 10 reputation, so I can't post the pic from the book, so I will paste the link.*

https://s32.postimg.org/g8divtz6t/Screen_Shot_2016_07_15_at_01_56_24.png

My question is- why does the special solution contain only two rows s1 and s2? I could take x=0, then the special solution could have an additional vector {0,1,-2/3}, no?

Comment: That solution is a linear combination of the two solutions Strang gives. The point is that the null space of the linear transformation defined by the $1\times 3$ matrix in the problem is two-dimensional, so a basis for it requires two independent vectors, but which two vectors you pick is not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why $s_1$ and $s_2$ are called special solutions.They are like a base for all the solutions (You should notice that this equation would have infinitely many solutions). Every vector in this nullspace could be represented in the form of $v=as_1+bs_2$.

In this case, $y$ and $z$ are the free variables, so you start with them. 
Set $y=r,\ z=s$, then $x=-2r-3z$.
Therefore the answer can be expressed in the form: $$v=r\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So I have two vectors because I would use two variables to express x, and in turn, I would give them the value of 1 and 0, to give the solution. If my thinking is correct, in case of a plane 2x+2y-2z-2t=0, I would express x as x=m+n-q, where m=z, n=t, y=q, and in this case the special solution would have three vectors?

Comment: Yes you are correct!